# Modificar y eliminar registros de una tabla PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo hecha la conexión a mi Base de Datos y tengo una tabla que filtra los registros en tiempo real con Ajax. Le he agregado los botones de eliminar y modificar pero no puedo hacerlos funcionar, he probado varios tutoriales pero la mayoría utilizan Json. 
Si alguien sabe donde puedo buscar la solución o como hacerlo, le agradezco.

Este es el código:

```
<body>
<h1 class="text-center titulo">Vehiculos</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-table">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-xs-6">
                        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">Buscar vehiculos</span>
                            <input id="filtrar" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese texto a buscar">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <center>
                            <th ><em style="margin-left: 50%;" class="fa fa-cog"></em></th>
                            <th>Dominio</th>
                            <th>Marca</th>
                            <th>Modelo</th>
                            </center>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="contenidobusqueda"> 
         <?php 

                //Guardamos en $query los datos de la consulta.
                //asi a $row en un array con los datos de $query

                $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT dominio,marca,modelo FROM vehiculos");
                for($i=0; $i<mysqli_num_rows ($query); ++$i){   
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        ?>
                            <tr>

                                <td align="center">
                                    <a class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger"><em class="fa fa-trash"></em></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row[0];?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row[1];?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row[2];?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-right">
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="../vistas/principalAdmin.php">Volver</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y tengo un javascript que es para buscar que es jsbuscar al que refiero en el código anterior

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        (function ($) {

            $('#filtrar').keyup(function () {

                var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
                $('.contenidobusqueda tr').hide();
                $('.contenidobusqueda tr').filter(function () {
                    return rex.test($(this).text());
                }).show();

            })

        }(jQuery));

    });
```

Comment: Donde esta el codigo que usas para editar o eliminar un registro? y tu ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Esta pregunta se parece mucho a una que ya había respondido antes, tal vez te sirva:

[Eliminar blob con ajax, boton dentro de modal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44459/eliminar-blob-con-ajax-boton-dentro-de-modal)

Básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Crear tus dos botones (Eliminar y Editar) con un evento onclick, lo puedes hacer con jquery con el id de cada botón
2. En tu función llamada desde el onclick de los botones debes mandar tu información a través de ajax, te recomendaría manda un ID de la tabla
3. En tu petición $.ajax debes poner la url de tu página PHP que va a procesar la petición
4. En tu página PHP procesas la información obteniendo los datos que mandaste desde tu tabla con las variables $_POST, $_REQUEST o $_GET

Te recomiendo validar que esta petición siempre venga desde tu sitio ya que cualquiera podría enviar peticiones desde otros sitios y borrar registros.