# Eliminar blob con ajax, boton dentro de modal

Tags: php, html5, ajax, modal

No puedo acceder a todos los datos ya que se queda en la primera iteración, es decir, solo puedo acceder al primer ID, este es necesario para poder borrar el archivo blob correcto. La parte de html es gigante ya que muestro primero la información en una tabla, y funciona la iteración, no así cuando está en las ventanas modales.

.js

```
<script class="javascript">
    function EliminarDatos(id, url){
       var nombre = $id;
       var url = url;
       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url: 'url',
           data:(nombre),
       });
    }
</script>
```

php

```
<?php 
  include "conexion.php";
  $rut=$_POST['id'];

  $query="DELETE CV FROM personalrrhh WHERE RUT='$rut'";
  mysqli_query($link,$query);
  header("Location: table_data_tables.php");

?>
```

HTML

```
       <div class="table-responsive">

                 <?php
                    //conexion
                    include "conexion.php";

                    //consulta bd
                    $query="SELECT * FROM personalrrhh";
                    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
                    $dato = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                 ?> 


                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" id="mitabla">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Segundo nombre</th>
                    <th>Apellido</th>
                    <th>Segundo Apellido</th>
                    <th>Rut</th>
                    <th>Codigo trabajador</th>
                    <th>Fecha Nacimiento</th>
                    <th>Teléfono</th>                        
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Email 2</th>
                    <th>Direccion</th>
                    <th>Ciudad</th>
                    <th>Comuna</th>
                    <th>Región</th>
                    <th>Direccion alternativa</th>
                    <th>Ciudad alternativa</th>                        
                    <th>Comuna alternativa</th>                        
                    <th>Región alternativa</th>
                    <th>Web</th>
                    <th>Contacto emergencia</th>
                    <th>Fono emergencia</th>
                    <th>Alergias</th>
                    <th>Grupo sangre</th>
                    <th>Valor HH</th>
                    <th>Sueldo base</th>
                    <th>Prevision Salud</th>
                    <th>Prevision Social</th>
                    <th>Documentos</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    do{
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['NOMBRE_1']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['NOMBRE_2']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['APELLIDO_PAT']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['APELLIDO_MAT']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo $dato['RUN'];?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo $dato['COD_TRABAJADOR'];?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo $dato['FECHANACIMIENTO'];?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo $dato['FONO1'];?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['CORREO_ELECTRONICO']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['CORREO_ELECTRONICO2']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['DIRECCION1']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['CIUDAD1']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['COMUNA1']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['REGION1']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['DIRECCION2']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['CIUDAD2']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['COMUNA2']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['REGION2']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['WEB_PERSONAL']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo $dato['NAME_EMERGENCIA'];?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['FONO_EMERGENCIA']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo utf8_encode($dato['ALERGIAS']);?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo $dato['GRUPOSANGRE'];?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo $dato['VALOR_HH'];?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo $dato['SUELDO_BASE'];?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo $dato['prevision_salud_ID_PREVSALUD'];?></p></td>
                    <td><p class="h6"><?php echo $dato['prevision_social_ID_PREVSOCIAL'];?></p></td>
                    <td><br><p> </p><button href="#ventana1" class="btn btn-primary  dim" type="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class=" fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></button></td>
                    <td><br><p> </p><button href="#ventana2" class="btn btn-primary  dim" type="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class=" fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></button></td>
                    <!--Modal que contiene los docs-->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="ventana1">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <!--Header de la ventana-->
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button tyle="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h2 class="modal-title">Documentos</h2>
                                </div>
                                <!--Contenido de la ventana-->
                                <div class="modal-body">

                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-w-m btn-link" >Curriculum Vitae</button><b>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</b>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Imprimir</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Descargar</button>

                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#ventana3" data-toggle="modal">Editar</button>
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="ventana3">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <button tyle="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                    <h2 class="modal-title">Subir Documento</h2>                                                        
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="cv" id="$id"></div>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-w-m btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" onclick="EditarDatos('<?php echo $dato['RUN'];?>','editar.php')">Guardar Cambios</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                   
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" onclick="EliminarDatos('<?php echo $dato['RUN'];?>','deletecv.php')">Eliminar</button>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Footer ventana-->
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-w-m btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }while ($dato = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
                ?>
                </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Hola Camilo, donde dice `.$ajax` deberia decir `$.ajax`. es un error al cargar la pregunta o esta asi en tu codigo? Puedes verificar que no sea este el error que tienes? gracias!

Comment: @EmanuelVe gracias, pero no era el problema, mi problema es que no pasa de la primera iteración al entrar a las ventanas modal, solo me capta   la primera id de la tabla, y no sigue avanzando a las otras filas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes revisar este link: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#95881

Lo están haciendo usando POO pero lo puedes traducir para que sea estilo por procedimientos.

Si te das cuenta en el ejemplo solo están poniendo todo el resultado en un array auxiliar:

```
while($row = $mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Luego puedes recorrer $rows

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{
  echo $row['NOMBRE_1'];
}
```